# Database creating 2 _id columns and having issues pulling Base64 string out

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am adding an auto incremented _id to my database and it's adding the column twice in my database when I look at it with Stetho. Also when I am trying to use my getEmployee method from an SQLiteOpenHelper I am getting that it can't read column 10 which is a column that I am saving a Base64 string to so I can parse it and generate the image to display with the employees other information. I am calling the database in another listView and I am having no issues getting that string.

MainActivity where I am creating and calling the database

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ListView mTopList, mDirectReportList;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private ArrayList<Employee> mEmployees = new ArrayList<>();
    private BottomListViewAdapter mBottomListViewAdapter;
    EmployeeDBHandler dbHandler;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter;
    private int mStartingEmployeeID = startingEmployeeNumber;
    private String table = "employees";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "Employee_number";




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dbHandler = new EmployeeDBHandler(getApplicationContext());
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);






        getXMLData();




        //GUI for seeing android SQLite Database in Chrome Dev Tools
        Stetho.InitializerBuilder inBuilder = Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this);
        inBuilder.enableWebKitInspector(Stetho.defaultInspectorModulesProvider(this));
        Stetho.Initializer in = inBuilder.build();
        Stetho.initialize(in);




    }


    public void getXMLData() {
        OkHttpClient client = getUnsafeOkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(getString(R.string.API_FULL_URL))
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                final String responseData = response.body().string();
                final InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseData.getBytes());
                final XMLPullParserHandler parserHandler = new XMLPullParserHandler();
                final ArrayList<Employee> employees = (ArrayList<Employee>) parserHandler.parse(stream);


                for (Employee e : employees) {
                     dbHandler.addEmployee(e);
                }


                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        displayTopList();
                        displayBottomList();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }


    public void displayTopList() {
        Employee singleEmployee = dbHandler.getEmployee(mStartingEmployeeID);
        Log.i("The first name is: ", singleEmployee.getFirst_name());
    }


    public void displayBottomList() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mBottomListCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM employees", null);


        ListView mBottomListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mDirectReportList);
        BottomListViewAdapter bottomAdapter = new BottomListViewAdapter(this, mBottomListCursor);
        mBottomListView.setAdapter(bottomAdapter);
    }
}
```

My EmployeeDBHandler that has the getEmployee method

```
public class EmployeeDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "OneTeam";
    private static final String TABLE_EMPLOYEE = "employees";


    //Employee table columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "Employee_number";
    private static final String KEY_FIRST_NAME = "First_name";
    private static final String KEY_LAST_NAME = "Last_name";
    private static final String KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE = "Phone_mobile";
    private static final String KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE = "Phone_office";
    private static final String KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE = "Payroll_title";
    private static final String KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS = "Has_direct_reports";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "Email";
    private static final String KEY_COST_CENTER = "Cost_center_id";
    private static final String KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE = "ThumbnailData";
    private final static String DB_CLIENTS_ID = "_id";




    public EmployeeDBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);


    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_EMPLOYEE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE + "("
                + DB_CLIENTS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_ID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_FIRST_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_LAST_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_COST_CENTER + " TEXT,"
                + "UNIQUE(" + KEY_ID + ")"
                + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_EMPLOYEE_TABLE);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //drop old table if existence
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE);


        //Create table again
        onCreate(db);
    }


    //Add new employee
    public boolean addEmployee(Employee employee) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID, employee.getEmployee_number());
        values.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME, employee.getFirst_name());
        values.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, employee.getLast_name());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE, employee.getPhone_mobile());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE, employee.getPhone_office());
        values.put(KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS, employee.getHas_direct_reports());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, employee.getEmail());
        values.put(KEY_COST_CENTER, employee.getCost_center_id());
        values.put(KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE, employee.getPayroll_title());
        values.put(KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE, employee.getThumbnailData());




        //Inserting Row
        database.replace(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, null, values);
        database.close();
        return true;
    }


    //Get single employee
    public Employee getEmployee(int employeeNumber) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Employee employee = null;


        Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, new String[]{
                        KEY_ID, KEY_FIRST_NAME, KEY_LAST_NAME, KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE, KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE,
                        KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_COST_CENTER, KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE, KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE}, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(employeeNumber)}, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                employee = new Employee(cursor.getString(0),
                        cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4),
                        cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8),
                        cursor.getString(9), cursor.getString(10), cursor.getString(11), cursor.getString(12),
                        cursor.getString(12), cursor.getString(14), cursor.getString(15), cursor.getString(16),
                        cursor.getString(17), cursor.getString(18), cursor.getString(19), cursor.getString(20),
                        cursor.getString(21), cursor.getString(22), cursor.getString(23), cursor.getString(24),
                        cursor.getString(24), cursor.getString(25), cursor.getString(26));
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        database.close();
        return employee;


    }


    //Get All Employees
    public ArrayList<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
        //Select all query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE;


        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


        //looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Employee employee = new Employee();
                employee.setEmployee_number(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
                employee.setFirst_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_FIRST_NAME)));
                employee.setLast_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_LAST_NAME)));
                employee.setPhone_office(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE)));
                employee.setPhone_mobile(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE)));
                employee.setHas_direct_reports(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS)));
                employee.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_EMAIL)));
                employee.setCost_center_id(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_COST_CENTER)));
                employee.setPayroll_title(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE)));
                employee.setThumbnailData(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE)));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }


        //return employees list
        return employeeList;
    }


    //Get Employee Count
    public int getEmployeeCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE;
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();


        return cursor.getCount();
    }


    //Updating single employee
    public int updateEmployee(Employee employee) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();


        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME, employee.getFirst_name());
        values.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, employee.getLast_name());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE, employee.getPhone_mobile());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE, employee.getPhone_office());
        values.put(KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS, employee.getHas_direct_reports());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, employee.getEmail());
        values.put(KEY_COST_CENTER, employee.getCost_center_id());
        values.put(KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE, employee.getPayroll_title());
        values.put(KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE, employee.getThumbnailData());


        return database.update(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(employee.getEmployee_number())});
    }


    //Delete single employee
    public void deleteEmployee(Employee employee) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        database.delete(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(employee.getEmployee_number())});
        database.close();
    }


    //delete row
    public void delete(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        if (db == null) {
            return;
        }
        db.delete(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, "Employee+number = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create _id column, SQLite creates it by default.
For convenience with positions you can use:

```
String str = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("column_name"));
```

This will allow you to fetch the column index from name but I think it can be slower.
If you do not want to use the method above you can also Log the following code to solve your confusion with any position, Just remove the code after debugging.

```
 int position = cursor.getColumnIndex("column_name");

enter code here
```

Comment: I removed the + DB_CLIENTS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," from the create table and it is still creating the _id twice and some reason starting at 124 not at 1.

Comment: Also I am trying to pull the whole row with the getEmployee method from my DbHandler but having a column 10 issue. Its not letting me pull the whole row because of that column.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the application also? if you won't delete the application or upgrade the version then the database won't be recreated.

Comment: I have deleted the application several times and everytime the application is reinstalled via Android Studio I am still seeing 2 _id columns and the number is starting at 160.